# How can I capture the console output of installed python packages and send them to my logger?

Tags: python, logging, console

I'm developing a python application and I want to have a nice console output when running the package. This is ruined by warnings, print statements, or other forms of console output inherited from installed packages (like `matplotlib`).

Example:

```bash
> python test.py

[10/04/2022 01:38:15 AM] INFO     Creating directory                             simulation.py:891                                                                
                         INFO     Saving GIF...                                  simulation.py:793
                         INFO     Finished saving GIF                            simulation.py:803
                         INFO     Saving graph...                                simulation.py:816
/blah/blah/blah/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py:1026: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  x = np.asanyarray(x)
[10/04/2022 01:38:16 AM] INFO     Finished saving graph                          simulation.py:827
```

So all of **my** log messages are captured by my configured logger across all of my modules, but then the console output is interrupted by ugly messages from installed packages that I don't care about and can't change.

**How do I send these messages (or all console output?) to my logger so that they are in the same format as my log messages?**

This happens across many different packages so I am not looking for a solution just for `matplotlib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redirect `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` to a logger, as described in the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.11/howto/logging-cookbook.html#how-to-treat-a-logger-like-an-output-stream).

**Update:** You can only redirect Python-level things using `sys.stderr` - the example in the comment is a C-level write. To redirect that, you'll need to use `ctypes` and the approach outlined in [this post](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/) in the section entitled "Redirecting with file descriptor duplication". Though I would log an issue with that library's maintainers, as outputting to stderr from a library isn't terribly good practice.

Comment: Thank you! This worked... mostly. It captured the matplotlib warning. Although I'm still running into annoying `fprintf` outputs to STDERR from [this library](https://github.com/Distrotech/reportlab/search?q=colinear%21), but that specific example wasn't a part of my original question. Do you have any idea how I might capture that as well?